# How can dhclient be made namespace aware?

Tags: linux, dns, dhcp, dhclient, linux-namespaces

I am using namespaces to separate a few physical interfaces on a server. The routing works perfectly.
Also I have a folder for each namespace in /etc/netns/ e.g. /etc/netns/namespaceA/resolv.conf so that DNS works fine as well.

The problem arises when using DHCP with dhclient.
I am running dhclient from inside a namespace and am getting this error.

```
(namespaceA)root@tc-vm:~#dhclient
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
mv: cannot move '/etc/resolv.conf.dhclient-new.2740' to '/etc/resolv.conf': Device or resource busy
```

I found out that the mv in /etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc contains a mv which might cause the problem.

How can dhclient be made namespace aware?

Answer (score 12):

I looked into the issue myself.

What happens is that when you create a network namespace, you see `/etc/resolv.conf` of the host machine unless you create explicitly `/etc/netns/<namespace_name>/resolv.conf`, which will bind mount automatically to `/etc/resolv.conf` when looked up *inside* the network namespace. Therefore, by simply creating that path, the `resolv.conf` of the host won't be visibile any more on the network namespace, which will have its own `resolv.conf`.

The [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html) of `ip netns` explains this:

> For applications that are aware of network namespaces, the convention
>          is to look for global network configuration files first in
>          /etc/netns/NAME/ then in /etc/.  For example, if you want a different
>          version of /etc/resolv.conf for a network namespace used to isolate
>          your vpn you would name it /etc/netns/myvpn/resolv.conf.
>
> **Ip netns exec automates handling of this configuration, file
>   convention for network namespace unaware applications, by creating a
>   mount namespace and bind mounting all of the per network namespace
>   configure files into their traditional location in /etc.**

As far as updating `resolv.conf`, `dhclient` doesn't work in network namespaces out of the box when `/etc/netns/<namespace_name>/resolv.conf` exists (on the other hand, when it doesn't exist, it will overwrite the `resolv.conf` of the host machine, since it's the only one available, but that's not really desirable). As the error in the question above shows, what happens is that `dhclient` prepares a temporary file with the new nameserver details in `/etc/resolv.conf.dhclient-new.2740` and then tries to rename it as `/etc/resolv.conf`. It generates an error because `/etc/resolv.conf` is already bind-mounted and apparently `mv` isn't allowed to do this trick.

In order to make `dhclient` work in network namespaces, `/sbin/dhclient-script` should be modified.
I removed this:

```
mv -f $new_resolv_conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

And replaced it with:

```
cat $new_resolv_conf > /etc/resolv.conf
rm -f $new_resolv_conf
```

Otherwise, `dhcpcd` seems to do this job correctly.

Comment: This is a cool workaround. Note that there are two sections where you have to change mv to cat.  I wonder what mv is interally doing. Is it removing the file first?

Comment: Almost 4 years later and this issue still persists (dhclient 4.4.2)